# CloudFront usually misses from browser, hits from cURL

Tags: http, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

When I load my HTML page in my browser, all requests for assets have `x-cache: Miss from cloudfront`. If I reload my browser *very* quickly, I can sometimes get a `Hit`.

If I open my developer tools and "copy request as curl", I reliably get a hit, no matter how fast or slowly I perform the requests.

Why would different user agents making the exact same request get a hit or miss?

Comment: Hey, it would be helpful if you could also add the behaviour settings for your route in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are fowarding the cookies on Cloudfront.

So every time you refresh the page in a browser, the browser creates a new cookie hash and the CDN thinks it's a new request.

You have to turn off cookie fowarding at Cloudfront.

To replicate this behaviour in CURL try sending the request with a different cookie and you will see it slowing down.